# Lookup filter for related entity in MSCRM for mobile

Tags: mobile, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

We are trying to have part of our CRM 365 environment available on mobile, but there are some problems with that. One of those is that we have a lookup field that normaly uses a custom view to filter results based on a related entity. It is currently using the `.addCustomView` function to create a view on the fly to filter the results. But, in my research about CRM mobile, I discovered that views could not be used to filter lookups on mobile : I had to fix multiple language filters with `addCustomFilter`. So, I tried to use `addCustomFilter` to create a filter for the lookup, but this function can't take conditions based on related entities.

Is there a way to create a filter with conditions based on related entities for a lookup filed in CRM for mobile ?